# Trouble identifying space char with isspace

Tags: matlab, removing-whitespace

Help!  For some reason my function is not identifying spaces on all sets of data.  See below:

I am using the following function in my code:

```
function [ll]=f_get_length(A)

 l1=length(A);
  for ii=1:l1
   if A(ii) == ' '
    ll=ii;
     break
   end
end
```

but I get to a dataset that gives the following error:

```
Error in ==> f_get_length at 3
l1=length(A);

??? Output argument "ll" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
"/home/geovault-01/abutcher/scripts/meghans_codes/SdP_codes/3DKirchhof/f_get_length.m>f_get_length".

Error in ==> process_sacdataSP10_PICASSO at 62
ll=f_get_length(SS);
```

When I try to figure out the problem, I discovered that the space is not being identified as a space when using `isspace`, but the following proves that there are spaces after the 4th character:

```
strtrim(A)
ans =
  CAVN

length(A)
ans =
  8

display(['test' A(6) 'test'])
  test test
display(['test' A(5) 'test'])
  test test
display(['test' A(4) 'test'])
  testNtest
display(['test' A(7) 'test'])
  test test
display(['test' A(8) 'test'])
  test test

length(A)
ans =
  8

strtrim(A)
ans =
  CAVN    

length(A)
ans =
  8

isspace(A(6))
ans =
  0

isspace(A)
ans =
  0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: There are many characters that show up as white space.  Try `A(6)==' '`   If it returns false then convert A(6) to a number to see what char it is.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no space in your input `A`, the output `ll` is not assigned.

To solve that problem, you should add at the end of your function:

`ll=l1;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `isspace` or the much more limited `A(ii) == ' '`, you could use the condition

```
A(ii) <= ' ' || isspace(A(ii))
```

The first part will take care of all non-printing ASCII characters (e.g., everything in ASCII that comes before space), and `isspace` will then take care of the remaining non-printing Unicode characters.

Alternatively, you could use

```
if ~isletter(A(ii)), break; end
```

and, as Oli already indicated, make sure that `ll` gets assigned *in all possible paths*. Meaning, your function will fail if `A = ''` (empty) or `A = char(1)` (NULL character) or `A = ' THE_REAL_STRING'` (it will return length 1 because of leading space), etc.

Moreover, you can vectorize the whole thing like so:

```
ll = find(A <= ' ' | isspace(A), 1);
```

making the whole loop unnecessary.